# how to compare x509certificates using a binary search

Tags: java, x509certificate, binary-search, comparable

I have a list and that list has an `x509certificate`, which I use for storing in a cms package. All dandy, until I bump into the problem: I can't have the same person signing twice.
So, I know how to find that certificate by equals, so a linear search.

It may sound pure vanity, but I would rather use a **binary search**, using, obviously, **`comparable`**.
How in heavens could i do that? (*java* or *bouncyCastle*).

Thanks

Comment: It implements both #equals(Object) & #hashCode() - i.e. you could use a hash map to look it up.

Comment: Or simpler yet, a HashSet. if (set.add(cert)) { ... }

Comment: I was thinking on searching by the serialnumber and as soon as I find compare the encoded bytes (.getEncoded())... what do you think?

Comment: but i liked your idea... I will think about it

Comment: i can sort and search by something like hash, or serialnumber, but the when i find it I will compare the DER objects in a encoded bytearray[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to thank [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967142/jens) and [dnault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611819/dnault) for guiding me to the answer:
I am going to sort and search the certificates using the (bigInteger) SerialNumber, which all certificates have,  to compare and as soon as I find a similar serial, I am going to compare them in a [DER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) encoded format.

Why did I not used the hash code approach, you may ask:
Not all the certificates and signatures will be in memory. Some, sometimes, will be in a PKCS7 (CMS), or a XMLDSig file. So The object's hashcode may differ, as physically they are different objects, but logically they refer to the same certificate.

Overriding getHashCode will only give half of the answer, as sometimes, not too often the serial number can occur twice, as it depends on the chain that it belongs to, among other factors.

Thank you for the info and the help.

Answer (score 2):

Store the certs in a `TreeSet` and use `Collections.binarySearch` to look for the cert of interest (you'll have to turn your `Set` into a `List` first).  Underlying a `TreeSet` is a `TreeMap` so if you don't like that implementation you can implement `SortedSet` and make your own.  If duplicate certs aren't a concern then store them in a `List` and sort it before calling `binarySearch`.

Is there a reason you don't want to use good ol' `Collection.contains`?

Comment: the thing is that bouncycastle and java's implementation of X509Certificate does not implements a comparable<X509Certificate> or comparable interfaces...

Comment: Then just go with a `HashSet`, `Set.contains()`, and move on to more important parts of the code.